# How to transform a strong generating set of $G \leq S_n$ to a set that generates a proper subgroup of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

Suppose $G \leq S_n$ and $S$ is a strong generating set of G. Before starting, I'll describe how $S$ is constructed in my particular case.

> - Suppose we have a subgroup chain $G = G_0 \geq G_1 \geq G_2 \geq \dotso \geq G_m = \{e\}$. Consider $G_i / G_{i+1}, 0 \leq i \leq m-1$. For each $i$ pick $e$ from $G_i$ and one element from each of the other cosets in $G_i / G_{i+1}$ forming a table of elements. This table of elements represents a strong generating set for G.
> - Let $G_{1...i} \leq G$ be the subgroup consisting of all those elements $g \in G$ such that $g(1)=1,\dotso g(i)=i$. Then $G \geq G_1 \geq G_{12} \geq \dotso G_{1...n} = \{e\}$ is a subgroup chain. $S$ is constructed based on this subgroup chain.

My problem is to construct a method that allows to find a generating set of a proper subgroup of $G$ by modifying $S$. The limitation is that this method should allow me to select a random subgroup for G. The goal is to repeat it recursively and construct
a random subgroup chain (meaning that the individual subgroups are picked randomly based on some rule).
I know that if $\langle S \rangle = G$ then $\forall \emptyset \neq S' \subset S, \langle S' \rangle \leq G$.
So the first idea is to remove some elements from $S$ and see what happens. The problem is that there's no guarantee that this subset will generate a *proper* subgroup of $G$.

I'm not really sure how to proceed. I don't know whether there is a general approach or one suitable for the specific strong generating set I have. The problem shouldn't be hard, but I need some direction. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want a *uniformly* random subgroup then this is probably very hard. It is similar in difficulty to counting subgroups. If you want just any old distribution of subgroups do something ad hoc, e.g., take $k$ random elements of $S^l$ for some integers $k, l$, and tune the values of $k$ and $l$ I guess.

Comment: @SeanEberhard the second one. What does $S^l$ denote here? $l-th$ column? And could you expand more on what you mean with tuning the values?

Comment: $S^l$ means $l$-fold product set. $S^l = \{s_1 \cdots s_l : s_1, \dots, s_l \in S\}$. I assume you are doing this on a computer. Just play with the values of $k$ and $l$ till you get something you're happy with. I don't understand what you want, so this may or may not be useful.

Comment: @SeanEberhard okay I see. this is a task from my prof and he's been pretty vague. But I assume there is a more theoretical approach. When I say random, I don't put any constraints on the distribution, e.g. if by any chance removing some number of randomly chosen elements from $S$ would result in a generating set of a proper subgroup, then I'd be pleased with this. In other words, I want to at least be able to generate different proper subgroups based on different values of some parameters(e.g. elements to remove from $S$)

Comment: You could for example consecutively delete random elements of $S$ until the group they generate is proper. Or you could just choose a single random element of $S$ to keep and throw away everything else, so you get a random cyclic subgroup (from a small collection).

Comment: @SeanEberhard but I assume the first one is algorithmically heavy? Initially $G = S_n$. If $t(n)$ is the complexity of finding whether $S'$ generates a proper subgroup, then the complexity of the final algorithm will be $O(t(n)n!)$. I get the gist though, but considering that we haven't really discussed any algorithms for finding whether $S'$ generates a proper subgroup, I assume there's a simpler approach somewhere there.

Comment: @SeanEberhard the second one accomplishes the short term task but the subgroup chain becomes more trivial. But I could play around this idea, e g. Check what the subgroup generated by 1 element from each row looks like for example.  The only problem is that I don't really have an algorithm for actually finding the subgroup generated by a subset which makes me wonder if there's a more theoretical approach. The prof suggested looking at horizontal products (let's say decreasing column numbers starting from $n$ or increasing and starting from 1),does this give any idea? I find it too vague for me

Comment: As for "actually finding the subgroup generated by a subset" -- in algorithmic permutation group theory, "having the group" is usually considered the same as "having a generating set". I.e., computationally, it makes more sense to identify a group with a list of generators than, say, the complete set of its elements. Then of course one has the problem of knowing when two groups are the same, but these things are well understood.

Comment: It seems to me that you are lack the necessary background to properly discuss these questions. Try a book on algorithmic group theory such as "Permutation Group Algorithms" by Seress, 2003. For now, the question is too vague and poorly motivated to give a satisfactory answer to, so I am voting to close.

Comment: BTW, why $O(t(n) n!)$? It is more like $O(t(n) |S|)$. And there are indeed good algorithms for testing whether a set generates the whole group. You can for example compute a strong generating set and use it to find the order of the generated group. Again, read the book of Seress. Or, if this is on a computer, just find the right commands and observe that they are fast (and read the documentation or source code to find out what's happening).